# Routing in ruby for controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to build a simple rails application however I get a routing error. Here is the controller:

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base

  def index

    @var = "Rails is amazing"

  end



end
```

Here is the routing:

```
get "/posts", to: "posts#index"
```

And the routing error is as following:

```
uninitialized constant PostsController
```

The url im accessing is this one:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts#
```

I understand that controllers should be pluralised in both the routing and in the name of the file. I am sorry for such a novice question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you have posts_controller.rb file in the controllers folder.In the `posts_controller.rb` file add the following syntax

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

end
```

In your routes file, try adding

```
resources :routes
```

In the terminal if you will type `CONTROLLER=posts rake routes`, you ll get the following output

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

Comment: Ah. So the file name must be posts_controller. I have given it the name of PostsController. That solved it. Thanks

Comment: one more quick question. It looks that when i do `%= @var %` The variable does not get printed into the view.

Comment: in your index.html.erb, you need to add `<%= @var%>`